# POST taxonomy item using Services module

Tags: services, 8

I want to POST a new taxonomy item. I'm using Postman in Chrome to test, I'm logged in fine, and I'm posting RAW JSON:

```
{
  "name": "building",
  "description": "",
  "vocabulary" : {
    "id" : 1,
    "resource" : "taxonomy_vocabulary",
    "uri" : "http://site/cms/taxonomy_vocabulary/1"
  }
}
```

And I just get this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<result>Access denied for user anonymous</result>
```

Comment: Change the content type to application/json

Comment: Thanks Clive, I had removed that accidentally. I've updated the question as I get a different message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the JSON format to add taxonomy term. I've tested it and works perfect.

```
{
    "vid": "2",
    "name": "Term Name",
    "description": "your description"
}
```

Here vid: vocabulary ID

Make sure the current logged-in user has privileges to add taxonomy term. and make sure to add token in *Headers* like follows

**name:** X-CSRF-Token

**value:** your-token

To know your token access the following path

```
yourdomain/services/session/token
```

Comment: Ah that's great, thank you! I find Drupals' messages and documentation lacking a great deal of sense and simplicity!

Comment: @MarkRobson you're welcome. Glad you solved your problem. :)